# My Breadcrumbs wont work when on a product page

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have breadcrumbs displaying at the top of my page perfectly fine and they work perfect as well, I can navigate using them, except when I am on a product page... for some reason they display the correct info but when I'm on a product page I can not click on them to use as a link. When I inspect the element the link src is still showing correctly it just wont let me click.

Here is my breadcrumbs code (started happening after upgrade to 1.9)

```
<?php
/**
 * Exotern
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade the extension to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.exotern.com for more information or
 * send an email to support@exotern.com .
 *
 * @category    Exotern
 * @package     Exotern_Crumbs
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Exotern (http://www.exotern.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

$crumbsLevels = $this->getAllBreadcrumbs();
?>
<?php if($crumbsLevels && is_array($crumbsLevels)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <?php foreach ($crumbsLevels as $crumbs): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumb): ?>
        <li <?php if ((!empty($_crumb['category_id']) || count($crumbs) < 4) && !$_crumb['last']) { ?>typeof="v:Breadcrumb"<?php } ?><?php if (!empty($_crumb['hidden'])) { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?>>
        <?php if(!empty($_crumb['link'])): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_crumb['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?>" <?php if (!empty($_crumb['category_id'])) { ?>rel="v:url" property="v:title"<?php } ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?></a>
        <?php elseif($_crumb['last']): ?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?></strong>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!$_crumb['last']): ?>
            <span>  </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: You have a bug in your CSS which pushes something over your link. Just open firebug or web deverloper toolbar, try to click on the link while selecting an element and you see which element is your problem

Comment: I had this before. It was because of some css "s...tuff". I had an element over the breadcrumbs and when I clicked the breadcrumb link I was actually clicking a div element. Check if that's the case for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a CSS problem

Comment: I also had the same problem before, there is an image div which comes over the breadcrumbs. This is a css issue.

Comment: i will look through my CSS files now thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was CSS related thank you for every one who helped. Just checked through the inspect element and i had my product view padding over the breadcrumbs so i removed that then moved the product view down. Now it works perfect. Thanks you

Comment: cant for 2 days apparently :( but i will :)